# FileInputStream not closed

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have the below code to set an Excel file:

```
public static void setExcelFile(String Path) throws Exception {
    try {
        FileInputStream ExcelFile = new FileInputStream(Path);
        ExcelWBook = new XSSFWorkbook(ExcelFile);
    } catch (Exception e){
        Log.error("Class Utils | Method setExcelFile | Exception desc : "+e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

This will be called from a loop in another class. This loop will be repeated for each Excel file in a location. Do I need to close the `FileInputStream` every time for each Excel file? If I am not closing at the end of each Excel file. Will it have an effect on memory utilization? Or everytime when the new Filestream object is created for next Excel file will it close the previous one automatically and create for current file? I faced an issue with following error message.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:58)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
  at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Cur.createElementXobj(Cur.java:260)
  at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Cur$CurLoadContext.startElement(Cur.java:2997)
  at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale$SaxHandler.startElement(Locale.java:3211)
  at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.piccolo.xml.Piccolo.reportStartTag(Piccolo.java:1082)
  at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.piccolo.xml.PiccoloLexer.parseAttributesNS(PiccoloLexer.java:1822)
  at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.piccolo.xml.PiccoloLexer.parseOpenTagNS(PiccoloLexer.java:1521)
  at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.piccolo.xml.PiccoloLexer.parseTagNS(PiccoloLexer.java:1362)
  at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.piccolo.xml.PiccoloLexer.yylex(PiccoloLexer.java:4682)
  at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.piccolo.xml.Piccolo.yylex(Piccolo.java:1290)
  at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.piccolo.xml.Piccolo.yyparse(Piccolo.java:1400)
  at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.piccolo.xml.Piccolo.parse(Piccolo.java:714)
  at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale$SaxLoader.load(Locale.java:3479)
  at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale.parseToXmlObject(Locale.java:1277)
  at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale.parseToXmlObject(Locale.java:1264)
  at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.schema.SchemaTypeLoaderBase.parse(SchemaTypeLoaderBase.java:345)
  at org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.WorksheetDocument$Factory.parse(Unknown Source)
  at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet.read(XSSFSheet.java:194)
  at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet.onDocumentRead(XSSFSheet.java:186)
  at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.onDocumentRead(XSSFWorkbook.java:354)
  at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocument.load(POIXMLDocument.java:166)
  at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:263)
  at utility...
```

Comment: As per the [Apache POI docs - don't use an InputStream when you have a File!](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#FileInputStream) Files are lower memory than streams

Answer (score 3):

If you do not close the stream, file will be locked until inputstream has been closed or JVM is shutdown. You should be closing stream otherwise you may run into IOException during next time reading that file from java or directly using windows

Answer (score 2):

You should add `ExcelFile.close()` [[ref](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#close%28%29)] in your catch block and after you are done using the resource. This is done to prevent memory leaks, and in your case, exceptions.

Answer (score 2):

From [`XSSFWorkbook(InputStream)`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFWorkbook.html#XSSFWorkbook(java.io.InputStream)):

> Constructs a XSSFWorkbook object, by buffering the whole stream into memory and then opening an [`OPCPackage`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/openxml4j/opc/OPCPackage.html) object for it.
>
> Using an `InputStream` requires more memory than using a File, so if a `File` is available then you should instead do something like
>
> ```
>        OPCPackage pkg = OPCPackage.open(path);
>        XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(pkg);
>        // work with the wb object
>        ......
>        pkg.close(); // gracefully closes the underlying zip file
> ```

As you have a path string you should use [`XSSFWorkbook(File)`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFWorkbook.html#XSSFWorkbook(java.io.File)) or simply [`XSSFWorkbook(String)`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFWorkbook.html#XSSFWorkbook(java.lang.String)).

As far as closing resources: [Always close streams](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=8). From [Java Practices -> Recovering resources](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=43):

> Expensive resources should be reclaimed as soon as possible, by an explict call to a clean-up method defined for this purpose. If this is not done, then system performance can degrade. In the worst cases, the system can even fail entirely.
>
> Resources include:
>
> - input-output streams
> - database result sets, statements, and connections
> - threads
> - graphic resources
> - sockets

Answer (score 0):

As others already told you: yes, you always should close the streams. Additionally, each unclosed and non-finalized stream will hold a file handle on some systems, and you might run into a total maximum value per process. (This depends on your OS.)

Probably, the easiest thing in your context above is to auto-close by using a try-with-resources construct:

```
try (
   FileInputStream ExcelFile = new FileInputStream(Path);
) {
  ExcelWBook = new XSSFWorkbook(ExcelFile);
} catch (Exception e) {
  Log.error("Class Utils | Method setExcelFile | Exception desc : "+ e.getMessage());
}
```